# How do you activate the Opera House map location? Noctropolis

Tags: noctropolis

I am reliving some childhood memories and playing Noctropolis. I am stuck. I have looked online and the walkthrough(s) espouse the ability to ask the "Hall of Records" clerk for its location[1,2]. When I visit the Hall of Records however, the clerk is unavailable and I do not have any items which "trigger" the sentinel statue to lower the receiving tray, etc...

Approximate state of my game: 
I have been to the Greenhouse
I have picked up the NEX poster, as well as the seeds and quickgrow liquid from the truck at the greenhouse
I have faced / limped away from Greenthumb *in* the Greenhouse
I have been to the Noose bar and spoken to the drunk CEO

I can not seem to get anyone to tell me (reveal) where the Opera House is. "Nek" and "Opera House" are conversational item in the conversational hex

What specifically do I need to do to trigger the appearance of Hall of Records clerk/how do I reveal the Opera House location?

1. [walkthrough reference]: https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/pc/564970-noctropolis/faqs/2063
2. [walkthrough reference]: https://www.walkthroughking.com/text/noctropolis.aspx`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Hall of Records" clerk was the key. I must have been playing with too much ambient light or glare or who knows but the "clerk" itself is hidden quite well - you need to simply "talk" to him (once you find him).

If you have your game progressed to the same state as described in the question, you will be offered dialog choices which will then yield the location of the Opera House

[image]